# Pandas - How to do 'group by' on multiple columns by various conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am stuck in grouping multiple columns using various conditions:

My dataframe looks like this:

```
code    product brand   lvl1    lvl2    lvl3     lvl4   lvl5        price
8968653 ABC             Milk    Mother  Toddler         Porridge    69
8968653 ABC     AB              Baby                    Bayi        95
```

Code and Product_name are the common fields.
All other columns should be grouped-by according as per following conditions:

1. Both the cells are empty : show NaN
2. One cell is empty : show other value
3. Both cells are non-empty :combine the cells by pipe
4. Price column should show the average

Expected output:

```
code    product brand   lvl1 lvl2        lvl3     lvl4  lvl5         price
8968653 ABC     AB      Milk Mother|Baby Toddler  NaN   Porridge|Bayi    82
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Erfan's, but build an agg dict, so to groupby just once:

```
# dictate which column does what
str_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['code','product', 'price']]
agg = {col:'|'.join for col in str_cols}
agg['price'] = 'mean'

# aggregation
new_df = df.groupby(['code','product'],as_index=False).agg(agg)

# strip by columns
# replace would be a better choice, but that'll be copied from Efran's
new_df[str_cols] = new_df[str_cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('\|'))
```

Output:

```
    code    product brand   lvl1    lvl2        lvl3    lvl4    lvl5            price
0   8968653 ABC     AB      Milk    Mother|Baby Toddler         Porridge|Bayi   82.0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in several steps:

1. First we get a list of columns which are `string` type and which are `numeric`
2. Second we use `groupby.agg` or `groupby.mean` depending on the fact if we have the `string` columns or the `numeric` columns:
3. We clean up our dataframe where there are unnecessary `|`.

```
# Step 1 get string and numeric columns
str_cols = df.iloc[:, 2:-1].columns
num_cols = df.iloc[:, -1:].columns

# Step 2 groupby on string and numeric columns
d1 = df.groupby(['code','product'])[str_cols].agg('|'.join)
d2 = df.groupby(['code', 'product'])[num_cols].mean()

# Join the dataframe back as 1
df = d1.join(d2).reset_index()
```

**Output 1:**

```
      code product brand   lvl1         lvl2      lvl3 lvl4           lvl5  price
0  8968653     ABC   |AB  Milk|  Mother|Baby  Toddler|    |  Porridge|Bayi     82
```

Now we clean up our dataframe by removing the pipes `|`.

```
df = df.replace('(^\||\b\|\b|\|$)', '', regex=True)
```

**Final output**

```
      code product brand  lvl1         lvl2     lvl3 lvl4           lvl5  price
0  8968653     ABC    AB  Milk  Mother|Baby  Toddler       Porridge|Bayi     82
```

Comment: Also `ABC|ABC` should be avoided. `lvl4` should be NaN.

Comment: This answer suffices for me. Plus`NaN` is not the biggest achievement here we can simply get it by using `df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)`. Didn't want to use a self defined function with many `if else` like yours, will probably be very slow. @harvpan

Comment: OP states that `df` should be grouped by `code, product`. Maybe it helps your answer.

Comment: @Erfan just following OP's requirements. :(((

Comment: Thank you for the tip @QuangHoang, that fixed it

Comment: I understand, but I like to think for myself. A small difference in `NaN` is not the reason for my to use `apply` with self defined function with many `if else`. Just my choice here :) @harvpan

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a function:

```
def f(x):
    if x.isna().all():
        return np.nan
    x = x.dropna()
    if x.dtype == 'int64':
        return x.mean()
    x = x.drop_duplicates()
    if len(x)>1:
        return '|'.join(x)
    return x


df.replace('', np.nan).groupby(['code'], as_index=False).agg(f)
```

Output:

```
      code product brand  lvl1         lvl2     lvl3  lvl4           lvl5  price
0  8968653     ABC    AB  Milk  Mother|Baby  Toddler   NaN  Porridge|Bayi     82
```